# Differences between two options to run a command

Tags: powershell, cmd

I tried to run the following command in two different ways:

```
get-service | where-object {$_.Status -eq 'Running'}
```

In the upper window I loaded the PowerShell and then the command
and in the lower both steps at once.

Generally the second option works fine,
what was the reason for the difference?

[The same command in two different ways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh2YG.jpg)

Comment: the first one is `powershell`, the second one just `cmd` (also called `batch` sometimes). They are very different "languages" (or maybe "interpreters" is a better word).

Comment: Do you by chance have a form of dyslexia? I mean no offence but I wanted to know because of your markup style is similar to another user who is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the command after powershell in quotes, then it will run

Comment: Thank you very much @guiwhatsthat!

Answer (score 1):

When PowerShell is invoked from a command prompt, use a string:

```
powershell "get-service | where-object {`$_.Status -eq 'Running'}"
```

(note the backtick in front of the $)

Or use a script block:

```
powershell  { get-service | where-object {$_.Status -eq 'Running'} }
```

Comment: Thanks!Thank you very much @DavidBrabant!